# adhoc struct/class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, class, anonymous-class

Currently i am using reflection with sql. I find if i want to make a specialize query it is easiest to get the results by creating a new class inheriting from another and adding the 2 members/columns for my specialized query. Then due to reflections in the lib in my c# code i can write foreach(var v in list) { v.AnyMember and v.MyExtraMember)

Now instead of having the class scattered around or modifying my main DB.cs file can i define a class inside a function? I know i can create an anonymous object by writing new {name=val, name2=...}; but i need a to pass this class in a generic function func(query, args);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) maybe it could serve your needs if you hide a Dictionary
behind your implementation of TryGetMember/TrySetMember.
There is a small example on this, follow the link.

Comment: Hey this is pretty cool. Maybe i can get the code modified to allow an object type and pass this in.

Answer (score 1):

Classes (types in general) can not be defined inside methods. Doh.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible (although not simple), but then the resulting class would not be known at compile time, so you wouldn't be able to use `v.MyExtraMember`. You would basically get a dynamically created anonymous object, so you would have to use reflection to access the extra members.